# Value from one controller should be available to other controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on angular application, I have multiple angular controllers.

Please find the sample code below:

```
app.controller('ctrlOne',function($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, MyService) {

//have some functionality here
$scope.loadCtrlOneData = function () {
        alert("loadCtrlOneData");
        MyService.getSIDResult().then(
            function (response) {
        //business logic
       })
}}

app.controller('ctrlTwo', function ($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, MyService) {
//some functionality here
function loadData() { //jQuery load to load the calendar in the field
MyService.getValueForDatePicker().then(
            function (response) {
              var cb = function(start, end, label) {
            //This function is called when user submit the date in datepicker
$('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                    }
})
}
 loadData();
})
```

The above code is the rough picture of my code. When the page is loaded ctrlOne and ctrlTwo are loaded. CtrlTwo is used to display the datePicker in the input field as shown in below code:

```
<input id="reportrange" ng-controller="ctrlTwo">
```

When the user picks the date from date picker and clicks on submit, again ctrlOne should be called and date value should be available in ctrlOne, where I have some logic to implement and again show the result on the browser.Please find the demo of datepicker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKsrQVmbxqq5Iqw3NEvI?p=preview).Please suggest how to call ctrlOne when the user selects the date and click on submit and date value should be available for ctrlOne.

Comment: Use a service provider in combination with observables.  In angular 2 you inject the provider dependency into the controller and can subscribe to a property on the provider.  Then one controller can push a value via `next` while the other one subscribes to property.

Comment: I'm using angularjs(angular1) @kyle

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the most elegant way to deal with your problem but if I understood right what you want to achieve I suggest to use angular event system. See [this](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/#rootscopeemitbroadcast) blog post for more details. Especially part with $rootScope.($emit/$broadcast).

To be more clear, you can use:
`$rootScope.$broadcast('someEventName', someValue)` in ctrlTwo and then

```
$scope.$on('someEventName', function (event, data) { //data passed in ctrlTwo })
```

in ctrlOne

Comment: But in my case all controllers are individual, there are no parent/child relationship. Can i use $broadcast still in controllerOne to get the value from controllerTwo.

Comment: That is why I suggested part with $rootScope. $rootScope is parent for all controllers.

Comment: $rootScope is not recognized in jQuery function  var cb = function(start, end, label) {..} .Please see date control demo http://plnkr.co/edit/qKsrQVmbxqq5Iqw3NEvI?p=preview(ctrlTwo)